# Load an html table from a mysql database when an onChange event is triggered from a select tag

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, onchange

So, here's the deal. I have an html table that I want to populate. Specificaly the first row is the one that is filled with elements from a mysql database. To be exact, the table is a questionnaire about mobile phones. The first row is the header where the cellphone names are loaded from the database. There is also a select tag that has company names as options in it. I need to trigger an onChange event on the select tag to reload the page and refill the first row with the new names of mobiles from the company that is currently selected in the dropdown list. This is what my select almost looks like:

```
<select name="select" class="companies" onChange="reloadPageWithNewElements()">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT cname FROM companies;";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['cname']."\">".$row['cname']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>
```

So... is there a way to refresh this page with onChange and pass the selected value to the same page again and assign it in a new php variable so i can do the query i need to fill my table?

```
<?php
//$mobileCompanies = $_GET["selectedValue"];
$sql = "SELECT mname FROM ".$mobileCompanies.";";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 
    echo "<td><div class=\"q1\">".$row['mname']."</div></td>";
}

?>
```

something like this. (The reloadPageWithNewElements() and selectedValue are just an idea for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the value in a hidden `input` :

`<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $row['cname'] ?>' id='someId' />`

in your JavaScript function use the value from this hidden input field:

```
function reloadPageWithNewElements() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('someId').value;
    // refresh page and send value as param
    window.location.href = window.location + '?someVal='+ selectedValue;
}
```

Now again in your PHP file retrieve this value from url for use as:

```
$someVal = null;

if (isset($_GET['someVal']) {
          $someVal = $_GET['someVal'];
}
```

see if this works!!!

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be using AJAX.

reloadPageWithNewElements() is a function which calls a page of your own site which will return the data you would like to put in your table.

If you are using JQuery, AJAX is very easy to implement:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/yourPage',
    data: { selectedCompany: $('.companies').val() },
    success: function(result) {
        //delete your tablerows
        $(".classOfTable tr").remove();
        //put the result in your html table e.g.
        $('.classOfTable').append(result);
    },
    dataType: html
});
```

The browser will send a request to "/yourPage?selectedCompany=Google" or something
All you have to do is let this page print out only html (maybe even easier is to print only the tablerow (<tr>).

If you have any further questions, please ask.

Comment: I prefer the get method solution. I understand this is optimal but i have no clue over AJAX.

Comment: like this?:
$.get or completely without jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery to do it.

first You need to add 'id' attribute to every option tag

```
<option id="option1">
<option id="option2">
```

and so on...
then with jQuery:

```
$('<option>').change(function() {
   var id=$(this).attr('id');
...save data here (i.e: with ajax $.post(url, { selected_id: id}, callback }
});
```